# Is there a way to open and play slides in android app programmatically

Tags: android

I want to take my powerpoint and open and play it in an Android App programmatically
Is there a way to do this via Intent?
If so is there a way to control the speed?

final Uri uri = Uri.parse(saveAsFileName); final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"); intent.setType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"); // PackageManager packageManager = clickit_appDelegate.getApplication().getPackageManager(); startActivity( intent);

Thanks

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Android App - Java, using Intent - but open to suggestions that would work

Comment: It's important to add code to your question with an edit and indent with four spaces for proper formatting. It's basically unreadable in a comment. Add the `java` tag to get the right attention here, too.

Comment: final Uri uri = Uri.parse(saveAsFileName); 
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
 intent.setType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"); 
// PackageManager packageManager = clickit_appDelegate.getApplication().getPackageManager(); startActivity( intent);

Comment: Please, *edit your question* to include any relevant code. Putting it in comments makes it very hard to read.